# How can I uninstall amazon app on ubuntu?

Tags: uninstall, amazon

I've tried using

```
sudo apt-get remove amazon
```

and the result was `sudo-apt-get: command not found`

and I tried

```
sudo apt-get remove amazon*
```

and I got

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'unity-webapps-amazoncloudreader' for regex 'amazon*'
Note, selecting 'ruby-amazon-ec2' for regex 'amazon*'
Note, selecting 'libnet-amazon-s3-tools-perl' for regex 'amazon*'
Note, selecting 'unity-webapps-amazon' for regex 'amazon*'
Note, selecting 'libnet-amazon-ec2-perl' for regex 'amazon*'
Note, selecting 'gamazons' for regex 'amazon*'
Note, selecting 'libnet-amazon-perl' for regex 'amazon*'
Note, selecting 'libamazon-sqs-simple-perl' for regex 'amazon*'
Note, selecting 'libnet-amazon-s3-perl' for regex 'amazon*'
Note, selecting 'flight-of-the-amazon-queen' for regex 'amazon*'
Note, selecting 'gmpc-plugin-coveramazon' for regex 'amazon*'
Package 'unity-webapps-amazon' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gmpc-plugin-coveramazon' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'flight-of-the-amazon-queen' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gamazons' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libamazon-sqs-simple-perl' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libnet-amazon-ec2-perl' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libnet-amazon-perl' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libnet-amazon-s3-perl' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libnet-amazon-s3-tools-perl' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'ruby-amazon-ec2' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'unity-webapps-amazoncloudreader' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
```

How can I remove this amazon application that was installed by default?

Comment: no im not talking about search results im talking about the app itself

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-webapps-common
```

Answer (score 5):

### Why this throws errors

```
sudo-apt-get remove amazon
```

The problem here is multiple

- its `sudo apt-get remove PACKAGENAME` not `sudo-apt get PACKAGENAME`
- You are guessing PACKAGENAMES (amazon) here

### How to locate package names and remove them

I would recommend to check what packagename you need to remove first and then remove it.

You could filter all installed packagenames for the string amazon first like this

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep amazon
```

This should output all installed package-names containing the string amazon.

Then - if you know which packagename you want to remove do as follows

```
sudo apt-get remove PACKAGENAME
```

or

```
sudo apt remove PACKAGENAME
```

As @Saikat Kundu mentioned already - the packagename you are looking in this particular case is `unity-webapps-common`.

Hope this helps understanding `apt`